# Postgresql keepalived gluster | FAULT state

Tags: python, centos7, keepalived

I am trying to achieve a simple failover using Keeplalived, postgres and gluster.

Using CentOs 7

I have mounted a replicated gluster volume on both nodes at '/var/lib/pgsql'.

```
Shared ip(Keepalived): 192.168.1.20
node01: 192.168.1.11
node02: 192.168.1.12
```

pgsql-check script contents :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys

try:
    subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'status', 'postgresql.service'])
    sys.exit(0)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    sys.exit(3)
```

Notify script contents :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

if sys.argv[3] == "MASTER":
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/systemctl start postgresql.service'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    sys.exit(0)

if sys.argv[3] == "BACKUP":
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'stop', 'postgresql.service'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    sys.exit(0)

if sys.argv[3] == "FAULT":
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/systemctl', 'stop', 'postgresql.service'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    sys.exit(0)

sys.exit(1)
```

keepalived.conf :

```
vrrp_script chk_pgsql {
  script       "/etc/keepalived/pgsql-check"
  interval 2   # check every 2 seconds
  fall 2       # require 2 failures for KO
  rise 2       # require 2 successes for OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.20
    }
    track_script {
        chk_pgsql
    }
    notify "/etc/keepalived/notify"
}
```

When the machines boot they enter FAULT state. But the main machine needs to enter MASTER state. When i start postgres manually and restart keepalived on the master everything is fine. When i try to do a failover, both machines have the FAULT state and don't recover.

Can anyone help with the config/scripts? Do i misunderstand the notify or check mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

When specifying a weight for the script of 1 like so:

```
vrrp_script chk_pgsql {
  script       "/etc/keepalived/check-pgsql"
  interval 1  
  fall 3      
  rise 1      
  weight 1
}
```

Then all of a sudden all works as expected. The default weight was 0.

I found this out after reading this link : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.keepalived.devel/2586

It is not the answer , but it pointed me in the right direction.

Current configuration :

```
vrrp_script chk_pgsql {
  script       "/etc/keepalived/check-pgsql"
  interval 1  
  fall 3    
  rise 1     
  weight 1
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 99
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    track_script {
        chk_pgsql
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.20
    }
    notify_master "/etc/keepalived/start-pgsql"
    notify_backup "/etc/keepalived/stop-pgsql"
    notify_fault "/etc/keepalived/stop-pgsql"
    notify_stop "/etc/keepalived/stop-pgsql"
}
```